# IoT-Edge edgeHub module back-off state

Tags: docker, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

i am trying to deploy a module into iot-edge device, for that i am following these [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart).

- Have an IoTHub subscription Created Edge Device in it Installed
  IoTEdge Runtime on my local machine (to act it like as a simulated
  device)
- Docker for windows is installed, up and running
  (Everything works well till here, as i checked the status of `Get-Service iotedge` command)
- Set up the Device module and used this `mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-simulated-temperature-sensor:1.0` as an image

after setting up the module on Microsoft Azure portal, edgeHub Module goes into back-off state. i have seen this issue [IOT-Edge Hub back-off state](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/531) and tried to restart docker as some of the comments suggested, but all in vain. 
i have also run the `docker logs edgeAgent` command to show you some logs, which are attached with this post.

[logs.txt](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/files/2339847/logs.txt)

**Edit:**
Attached are the statuses from Azure

### [image]

[image]

And this one is the status of iotedgeruntime

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I have recreated iotedge device on azure and then reinstall iotedgeruntime on my windows machine. without creating a module. following are the logs

```
> iotedge logs edgeAgent

[09/03/2018 10:22:32.855 AM] Edge Agent Main()
2018-09-03 15:22:33.043 +05:00 [INF] - Starting module management agent.
2018-09-03 15:22:33.182 +05:00 [INF] - Version - 1.0.1.15962126 (6e5e86dcf0c9a3732fc72a64d9ec9b0fcb2d6fad)

2018-09-03 15:22:33.298 +05:00 [INF] - Edge agent attempting to connect to IoT Hub via Amqp_Tcp_Only...
2018-09-03 15:22:34.360 +05:00 [INF] - Created persistent store at C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\edgeAgent
2018-09-03 15:22:39.749 +05:00 [WRN] - Empty edge agent config was received. Attempting to read config from backup file (backup.json) instead
2018-09-03 15:22:39.751 +05:00 [INF] - Edge agent config backup file does not exist - backup.json
2018-09-03 15:22:43.239 +05:00 [INF] - Edge agent connected to IoT Hub via Amqp_Tcp_Only.
2018-09-03 15:22:46.031 +05:00 [INF] - Deployment config in edge agent's desired properties is empty.
2018-09-03 15:22:46.050 +05:00 [ERR] - Error refreshing edge agent configuration from twin.
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.Core.ConfigSources.ConfigEmptyException: This device has an empty configuration for the edge agent. Please set a deployment manifest.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.IoTHub.EdgeAgentConnection.UpdateDeploymentConfig() in C:\agent\_work\1\s\edge-agent\src\Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.IoTHub\EdgeAgentConnection.cs:line 187
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.IoTHub.EdgeAgentConnection.RefreshTwinAsync() in C:\agent\_work\1\s\edge-agent\src\Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Agent.IoTHub\EdgeAgentConnection.cs:line 148
```

---

This log shows EdgeAgent is started but had an issue to work with empty deployment configurations. so i created an empty configuration. mentioned here https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-v1/issues/441#issuecomment-350824433. Then the same issue came up. Showing the log of following command.

```
> Get-WinEvent -ea SilentlyContinue `-FilterHashtable @{ProviderName="iotedged";  LogName = "application"; StartTime = [datetime]::Today} |select TimeCreated, Message |sort-object @{Expression="TimeCreated";Descending=$false} |format-table -autosize -wrap
```

**Logs file**

```
 TimeCreated         Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    -----------         -------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged::app -- Starting Azure IoT Edge Security Daemon                                                                                                                                                                               
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Initializing the module runtime...                                                                                                                                                                                         
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Using runtime network id nat                                                                                                                                                                                               
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged::app -- Version - 1.0.0 (52ef77db24126bf473265fc09c53d35290a2dd6b)                                                                                                                                                            
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged::app -- Using config file: C:\ProgramData\iotedge\config.yaml                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged::windows -- Starting iotedged service.                                                                                                                                                                                        
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Configuring C:\ProgramData\iotedge as the home directory.                                                                                                                                                                  
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Finished initializing the module runtime.                                                                                                                                                                                  
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Transparent gateway certificates not found, operating in quick start mode...                                                                                                                                               
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Finished configuring certificates.                                                                                                                                                                                         
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Initializing hsm...                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    9/3/2018 3:22:07 PM info: iotedged -- Configuring certificates...                                                                                                                                                                                                
    9/3/2018 3:22:08 PM info: iotedged -- Finished initializing hsm.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:22:08 PM info: iotedged -- Detecting if configuration file has changed...                                                                                                                                                                             
    9/3/2018 3:22:08 PM info: iotedged -- Change to configuration file detected.                                                                                                                                                                                     
    9/3/2018 3:22:08 PM info: iotedged -- Removing all modules...                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    9/3/2018 3:22:09 PM info: iotedged -- Finished removing modules.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:22:09 PM info: iotedged -- Provisioning edge device...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    9/3/2018 3:28:09 PM info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Checking edge runtime status                                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:28:09 PM info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Edge runtime is running.                                                                                                                                                                                     
    9/3/2018 3:28:12 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:12.431950 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                      
    9/3/2018 3:28:17 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:17.442486300 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:22 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:22.448494200 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:27 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:27.469429300 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:32 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:32.471719400 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:37 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:37.485219700 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:42 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:42.500957700 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:47 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:47.511517800 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:52 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:52.517649100 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:28:57 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:28:57.533708400 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:02 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:02.543274600 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:07 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:07.554093 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                      
    9/3/2018 3:29:09 PM info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Checking edge runtime status                                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:29:09 PM info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Edge runtime is running.                                                                                                                                                                                     
    9/3/2018 3:29:12 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:12.567305200 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:17 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:17.575885700 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:22 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:22.590898700 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:27 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:27.599495900 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:32 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:32.611798600 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:37 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:37.620460100 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:42 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:42.621030200 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 449 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:29:42 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [work] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:42.745729500 UTC] "POST /modules/%24edgeAgent/genid/636715662943777437/encrypt?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 985 "-" "-" pid(any)                                    
    9/3/2018 3:29:43 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:43.740061700 UTC] "GET /identities/?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 210 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                               
    9/3/2018 3:29:44 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:44.067628900 UTC] "PUT /identities/%24edgeHub?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 98 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                      
    9/3/2018 3:29:46 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:46.999173700 UTC] "POST /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 201 Created 908 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                             
    9/3/2018 3:29:47 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:29:47 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:47.247618 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                    
    9/3/2018 3:29:47 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:29:47 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:47.460481300 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:29:52 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:52.039166500 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:29:52 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:29:58 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:29:58.058868200 UTC] "GET /modules/edgeAgent/logs?api-version=2018-06-28&follow=false&tail=all HTTP/1.1" 200 OK - "-" "iotedge/0.1.0" pid(any)                                    
    9/3/2018 3:30:03 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:03 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:03.261676500 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:03 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [work] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:03.317280 UTC] "POST /modules/%24edgeAgent/genid/636715662943777437/encrypt?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 985 "-" "-" pid(any)                                       
    9/3/2018 3:30:08 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:08.632153200 UTC] "GET /modules?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 831 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                                                   
    9/3/2018 3:30:08 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [work] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:08.633152900 UTC] "POST /modules/%24edgeAgent/genid/636715662943777437/encrypt?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK 985 "-" "-" pid(any)                                    
    9/3/2018 3:30:08 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:08.802696300 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/stop?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 304 Not Modified - "-" "-" pid(any)                                                             
    9/3/2018 3:30:08 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container already in this state                                                                                                                                                                              
    9/3/2018 3:30:08 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:08 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:08.929044700 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:09 PM info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Checking edge runtime status                                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:09 PM info: edgelet_core::watchdog -- Edge runtime is running.                                                                                                                                                                                     
    9/3/2018 3:30:09 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:09 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:09.086215200 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:14 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })                                                                                                                                                                 
    9/3/2018 3:30:14 PM info: edgelet_http::logging -- [mgmt] - - - [2018-09-03 10:30:14.661189 UTC] "POST /modules/edgeHub/start?api-version=2018-06-28 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error 294 "-" "-" pid(any)
```

it shows initially edgeAgent started, but as soon as a deploy a module, then its showing the same error as i have mentioned above.

Comment: Are you trying to add edgeHub on a different network? From edgeAgent logs I'm seeing that it was trying to add edgeHub into a HN network? Another thing that I saw on the logs was some problem on edgeAgent trying to communicate with docker to create edgeHub. Since you are on windows, can you get the service logs and share as well? Follow steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot . Last, feel free to open a github issue, I believe there is one there regarding backoff, don't know if it was yours.

Comment: i am not trying to add edgeHub on different network, just following the documentation. don't know if it is doing so (as i am new to all this). i have opened this issue on GitHub too. https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/240

Comment: @AngeloRibeiro i have updated my post. have a look.

Comment: Yeah, from the logs it is some problem with docker to create the edgeHub Container. Here is the line when the problem happens: 9/3/2018 3:29:47 PM warn: edgelet_utils::logging -- Container runtime error - ApiError(ApiError { code: InternalServerError, content: Some(Object({"message": String("failed to create endpoint edgeHub on network nat: HNS failed with error : The process      
                        cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. ")})) })

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, from your logs, looks like you are having a docker for windows issue. 
I've found some github issues with very similar problems.

There are a couple of things you can do: 
Some people resolver by resetting docker (removing all existing docker images) or by doing this: 
- Uninstall Docker
- Remove Containers windows feature
- Reboot
- Enable Containers windows feature
- Install Docker

I understand the other option is awful and time consuming, I'm just forwarding what helped others.

Comment: I tried the first solution. but it didnt helped me. Even i removed the device from azure, remove docker images and tried to clean and re-create everything. but it happens everytime.

i will try to give a try to reinstall docker for window. then i will let you know.